# Troubleshooting IE 9 SSL certificate error

Tags: facebook, internet-explorer, ssl

I have a Facebook canvas app that calls various external files over https. When loading FB over http and then navigating to the app, I get the message "Internet Explorer blocked this website from displaying content with security certificate errors."

I realize there could be any number of culprits in a mixed environment, but how to best troubleshoot the specific request(s) that trigger the error? The IE dev tools don't provide a clue, as the error is not reported in the network or console tab. When I view the same page in Chrome, I get no SSL error, so I can't find a clue there.

Essentially what I've done so far is to proceed by clicking "show content", logging all the https requests in Charles, then trying them all individually in IE to see if any trigger the error out of context.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

The F12 Tools Console typically will show the exact source of a HTTPS error, as will the Fiddler Web Debugger. Is there a repro URL we could look at?

Comment: You'd think it would, but it doesn't. The "blocked" content is either not in the network panel of dev tools, or it's there with no indication that it's blocked.

Comment: Yes, I'd think that because I've never seen it fail. Without either a repro URL or a traffic capture, no one is going to be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have fiddler or httpwatch to figure out whether the request is being forwarded to another secured (https) URL?

Comment: I'm using Charles. The problem is that, out of many many requests, I don't know which request is tripping IE's security. If I knew which was "the" request, I'd be home free :)